# I can't add admob code interstitial android

Tags: android

hi guys sorry about my english,
I have problem in my application Android , I have code panner in apps it's working! but I don't have code interstitial in application, I tried to enter this code
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced

*add under `public class MainActivity extends AbstractContentActivity{`

find this problem in eclipse :

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Cannot override the final method from AbstractActivity
- overrides 
 com.ex.activity.AbstractActivity.onCreate
```

Comment: remove the final before the method onCreate in AbstractContentActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over `AbstractActivity`, remove the `final` keyword from `onCreate` and then you'll be able to extend it properly. Also note that in their example they're using just a plain `Activity`.

If you can't modify `AbstractActivity`, look at it's code it must have an extension point (overridable method) which will be called from `onCreate`.